# stepper motor power factor

Tags: power, motor, stepper-motor

can we set stepper motor (variable reluctance) motor to power factor 1(ideally) or close to 1 like 0.98-0.99 ?
What are the most basic techniques ?

Best regards!

Comment: No you cannot.   In general since all powers are dynamic lossy inductive with negative BEMF impedance .... but you can certain have Active PFC on your supply.  To make any lossy inductor have pf=1 you need a “complex conjugate “ RC matched impedance as the RL are both dynamic with speed position and dynamic loading. The lossy part is doing work in mechanical power.(shunt) as well as series DCR losses

Comment: found this https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-switched-reluctance-motor-drive-system-with-and-Mohamadi-Rashidi/a2e85b1922d4346ca53d71265ab9dadce37b3d9c

Comment: or it is off topic ?

Comment: On topic but read my reply again and understand it same as paper... “Front end”

Comment: You have to consider the application. If the stepper motor is energized and stopped it may have a power factor of 1 at the point (unless it's switched current source) but if the motor is dynamically stepping at high speed (and never stopping) then you could consider power factor control.

Comment: The pf of a stepper motor is never =1 unless inductance =0 at which point it is only a resistor. It can have negative resistance from back EMF but never 0 inductance. The front end or power supply uses a cap to resonate with 0 phase gift with linear impedance to load on the chopped input  AC current . Then it down converts to DC. This is available now for PC PSU’s and mandatory now for high power AC to DC supplies

Comment: Shift not gift SIRI

Comment: If the input is sinewave 50 Hz and we put LC resonant (resonant frequency) filter in series with motor ?

Comment: If the input is sinewave 50 Hz and we put LC resonant (resonant frequency) filter in series with motor the we will haave sinewavelike input current. Then if we connect second power factor connecting capacitor perhaps it will give very good pf correction?